# WCF Service WindowsPhone - EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: wcf, windows-phone

I'm developing solution within WCF Service and Windows Phone client application. The problem is I cannot connect to service even that in emulator when I type address of service in Internet Explorer I get right result.
My config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyCustomService" 
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                         maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                         enableHttpCookieContainer="true"
                          />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:2395/MyCustomService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyCustomService"
                contract="MyService.IMyCustomService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyCustomService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CustomResponse))]
public interface IMyCustomService
{
        [OperationContract]
        CustomResponse GetData();
}
```

My Problem is that each time i try to call on client proxy GetDataAsync() method, the completed event is not fire up and I get "EndpointNotFoundException". I've tried all solution which I found and none of them helped me. I also try to make WPF test client and it works correctly but Windows Phone app does not.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is your client configuration, e.g. the phone. Your pointing to localhost, but since you´re in the emulator on the phone localhost resolves to the same, not your PC where the service is hosted.

```
address="http://localhost:2395/MyCustomService.svc"
```

Put your PC´s hostname in there and you should be fine

Comment: Unfortunatley doesn't work. I even put it on the internet and still. EndpointNotFound exception is thrown. (It's occured aswell on emulator and device)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I have no idea how it started work but it did. I upload my service to internet hosting and  delete all service reference from my phone client project and add them again with internet address and it works now. Thx for your help Dominik.